# Deriving KKT Conditions for time-step equations

Tags: kkt-conditions, dual, lagrange-multipliers

I have a variable $e(h)$, and below is the part of the Lagrangian equation where I am taking the derivative with respect to $e(h)$.

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial e(h)} \hspace{.2cm}\mu_1(h)(e(h)-\bar{E})+\mu_2(h)(e(h)-e(h-1))$$

where $\bar{E}$ is a parameter and the rest are variables. $h$ defines the time steps in hours. Please let me know how to take the derivative to derive the KKT especially the part where the $e(h-1)$ is present.

Comment: If $e(h)$ and $e(h-1)$ are different variables, then the derivative of $e(h-1)$ with respect to $e(h)$ is zero.

Comment: $e(h)$ and $e(h-1)$ are the same variable, it's just the time step is different.

Comment: What does a solution look like to you? If it is a list of values for $e(h)$ for each finite number of possible $h$ values, then these are different variables.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that.

Comment: Is there any relationship between $\mu_1(h)$ and $e(h)$ or are they independent? Could you say something regarding $\mu_1(h)$'s partial derivative in terms of $e(h)$

Comment: $\mu_1(h)$ is the dual variable of the equation $e(h) <= \bar{E}$.